# How do I list only Watson IoT Platform services using 'bx service' or similar operations

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, watson, watson-iot

I'm trying to list out all the services of Watson IoT Platform, as deployed against a given Organisation and Space.

Say, for example, I have 3 different Watson IoT Platform services deployed and now, when I use
"bx service list"
It lists all services, including Watson IoT Platform services.
Now, if I know the name of my Watson IoT Platform service, then I can type in
"bx service show iotf-service"

Are you aware of BX SERVICE command or an equivalent REST API that I can leverage, to obtain the needed output?

Answer (score 0):

there isn't a bx service command to show you only the desired services, but (assuming that you are on windows) you can use:

bx service list | find "iotf-service"

this will grab only the "iotf-service"